# C++ push_back, pop_back. Getting error: vector subscript out of range

Tags: c++, loops, vector

If someone could look through my code, I can't seem to find the problem with it but I'm sure that I'm just not understanding something about the push_back/pop_back functions.

The program is designed to create a vector that takes user input and stops when the user types "stop".

It's definitely the pop_back that's giving me this error but I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong or how to change it, any help is appreciated.

Code:

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
using namespace std;


int main(){

    vector<string> animals;

    vector<string> ages;
    int const SIZE = 5;
    string stopCheck = "stop";
    string tempUserInput;
    int i = 0;

    //Loop used to gather user input and store it into array, animals and array, ages
    cout << "Please enter up to 5 animal names and ages, or type 'stop' to end" << endl;

    while( i<5 ) {
        cout << i << endl;
        // Taking user input for NAMES

        cout << "Enter the name of an animal: ";
        cin >> tempUserInput;
        animals.push_back(tempUserInput);
        cout << endl;

        cout << animals.size() << endl;

        //Function that automates the tolower function by applying it to each    element automatically
        //transform(animals[i].begin(), animals[i].end(), animals[i].begin(), tolower);

        cout << animals.size() << endl;

        //Checking for a stop input
        if (!animals[i].compare(stopCheck)){
            animals.pop_back();
            i = 5;
        }
        i++;

        return 0;
    }
```

It's not copying 100% correctly but assuming my initializations are right and the problem is the while loop I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to do this *before* `push_back`? `if (tempUserInput==stopCheck) { break; }`

Comment: Your debugger should tell you the line where the error happened. "vector subscript out of range" means you did something like `some_vector[index]` where `index` is >= `some_vector.size()`, meaning you accessed an element that doesn't exist.

Comment: What's exactly your problem?